# Main Electric Service Panel - Pull Wire

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Have square D service Panel and has QO breaker in it.

I am excited to pull wire through service Panel. I have lots of space left for new breaker at the bottom of the panel.

In the highlighted picture, is it completely ok to pull wire like this ?

Or what is the best way to pull wire in this service panel ?

[image]

Any help and suggestion is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Whoever framed that service panel was a genius (it does raise a question as to *what holds it in place; hopefully more than insulation sheeting/drywall!)  Also I would have left more clearance below, because that is where big cables will come in.

Comment: It would be much better to have your outbound circuits come in from the sides on the lower part of the panel.  You've put them at the top, partly in the way of the neutral bars and the main lugs may be insulated, but if you can't turn off the line side of a panel, it's much better to stay away from it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're OK to do what you want. Just make sure the holes in the 2x4's are back far enough so screws won't pierce the cables when installing drywall or install nail protectors to protect the cable.

Also, you need to install protective bushings on each cable going into the panel. You can't just stick them through a knockout and leave them that way. Get something similar to the item shown below. There are different types so check with your guy at the electrical supply store.

[image]

It's hard to see how your ground wires are connected but they should be on a different busbar than your neutrals but should be bonded to them.

Comment: I'm not a fan of those when you have access to both sides of the hole. They only allow one cable per clamp.

Comment: Agree with you Harper for the same reason you have mentioned. I personally use these. I used a lot on recessed can. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-4-in-Non-Metallic-NM-Twin-Screw-Clamp-Connectors-5-Pack-20512/100134407